# "Storage is not configured properly" error in the Azure Function Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am on a free tier and doing hands on the Azure function app. I am getting the storage error "Storage is not configured properly" on the overview page of my function app. When I create a function app, I do not get the option to create/use storage account. Also, I have tried adding the AzureWebJobsStorage manually in the function apps configuration settings and used the Access keys under my storage account but it does not work.

Please refer to the screenshots:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B2RM.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXyEZ.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1lut.png

Comment: Same issue here. Fairly certain I'm usually prompted to select a storage account when creating a new function app. I can say with certainty that this is the first time I've encountered a storage account configuration issue with my function apps. I'll let you know what I figure out.

Comment: Is your function v3? What version of storage do you have connected to it?

Answer (score 5):

If you're on the free trial, according to the Azure Chat Support person I just got off the line with, there are some hidden limitations when it comes to creating Azure resources from the Azure Portal.

You can, however, create a new function app from within Visual Studio Code. I just did so, on my free tier account, and it created the associated storage account as well.

Odds are you could do the same via Azure CLI but I haven't looked into that since it worked fine using VSC.

Here's a link on creating a function app from Visual Studio Code and publishing it to Azure: [Quickstart: Create a C# function in Azure using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-csharp)

Chat support is remarkably quick if you're on the free tier, btw. Scroll the left hand menu all the way to the bottom and  click on New support request.

Good luck!

Comment: Reporting from 2023, and I just wanted to note that they never bothered to fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I am encountering the same issue, but only when trying to use a managed identity to connect to the storage account.

I have both a SMI and > 1 UMI on my Function App.

In configuration I have the following two settings:

```
AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName = myStorageAccountName
AzureWebJobsStorage__credential = managedidentity
```

With this setup, I expect that the Function App should use the system-assigned identity as specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob&pivots=programming-language-csharp#common-properties-for-identity-based-connections).

I have also set `AzureWebJobsDashboard__accountName`, that should enable me to view logs in the Monitor tab. Logging only works when I choose *App Insights Logs* and not *Filesystem Logs*:
[image]

I am using a service bus trigger and HTTP triggers, and the system-assigned identity is assigned the role `Storage Blob Data Owner` on the same storage account specified in `AzureWebJobsDashboard__accountName`:

[image]

However, I cannot seem to get rid of this warning and even after scouring the documentation I cannot find what is missing.

[image]

Service bus and HTTP triggers are working fine, but I haven't done any tests to see if it scales.

No troubleshooting step [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account) is applicable or solves the issue:

- Storage account exists
- Application settings are there
- Credentials should be valid as am I using managed identity with properly assigned roles
- Not in a virtual network or behind a firewall
- No daily execution quota exceeded
- No log statement in the connected application insights workspace stands out

In fact, in log analytics I can see a ton of requests to retrieve an access token using managed identity, but they all are for application insights, I can't find any requests against the storage account:

```
ManagedIdentityCredential.GetToken succeeded. Scopes: [ https://storage.azure.com/.default ]
```

Where `_ResourceId` is:

```
/subscriptions/mySubscription/resourcegroups/myResourceGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/components/myApplicationInsights
```

In fact, I cannot find a single request that has *failed* to require token using managed identity:
[image]

**Update**
I managed to solve this, and thought I'd share what solved my issue.

I am running Consumption, and the documentation clearly states that this requires [`WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentazurefileconnectionstring) and [`WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_contentshare). After I added these, my warning is gone and the app scales properly.

Comment: I am experiencing the same warning, having configured the underlying function host storage account to use only RBAC and disabling host keys on it alltogether. This is intentional. I have read that this warning is due to the fact that Azure File share do not support something else than plain-text credentials with Functions. And the file share hosts the app content. Now, since the app content cannot be loaded from the file share, it uses internal storage (limited), which effectively limits the ability to scale above. Hence the warning. Somewhat plausible to me, but cannt find the source unftly.

Comment: It is true that Azure Files has limited support for different auth mechanisms. I've only found this information in different discussions around the web as well. However my issue was solved by adding `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` and `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE`. I am running Consumption, and the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings) clearly state that these are required. Once I added  these my issue was gone.

Comment: Leaving this exact two settings out of my bicep deployment template was the only way for my function to start up, albeit with above warning message regarding the scale limitation (which is not an issue for me). I had to do this since I have completely deactivated the host key auth on the underlying storage account (so connection strings don't work). Now anything in my function context  must use Entra (AAD) auth

Comment: TLDR; The last paragraph is what solve my issue too.

Answer (score -1):

**Storage account is inaccessible**

Your function app must be able to access the storage account. Common issues that block a function app's access to a storage account are:

The function app is deployed to your App Service Environment (ASE) without the correct network rules to allow traffic to and from the storage account.

The storage account firewall is enabled and not configured to allow traffic to and from functions. For more information, see Configure Azure Storage firewalls and virtual networks.

Verify that the allowSharedKeyAccess setting is set to true which is its default value. For more information, see Prevent Shared Key authorization for an Azure Storage account.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account