# Azure functions scaling error on Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-logic-apps

I get "***getting Scale out issues detected Storage is not configured properly, Function scaling will be limited. Click to learn more.***" error in azure portal while in azure function apps.
It is on consumption model.

I followed the Microsoft guide-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-recover-storage-account#storage-account-was-deleted
and other answer here and added the missing values WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and
WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE(I only have AzureWebJobsStorage set right now).

When I then run my logic apps, all azure functions return 404 not found. I had to delete WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING and WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE to make them work again.

**My concern is how to fix this because we are also facing performance issues and I am not sure if this scaling issue is contributing to it?**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Below might be reasons for getting the error,

- Region for storage account and function app are different.
- Region for storage account and logic app are different.
- App service plan is different for logic app and function app.
- Check whether AzureWebJobsStorage and WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING values are same or not in standard logic app configuration.
  [image]
- Check the AzureWebJobsStorage in function app is matching with the value of AzureWebJobsStorage in standard logic app configuration.

Check below links that may helps you,

Reference [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/870514/storage-is-not-configured-properly-error-in-the-az) 1

Reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67444188/storage-is-not-configured-properly-error-in-the-azure-function-apps) 2

Comment: Thanks @Vijaya for the detailed answer, i am planning to add the settings via arm template. However, is it any way possible to check how performance is improved after this change?

Comment: Yes You can try Log analysis to identify any performance issues related to the settings you have added via the ARM template and Azure Monitor to monitor the performance metrics of your Azure Function App